# Is there a more lightweight way to get a tuple of variable length?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to come up with a tuple that contains a value followed by some None values. The number of None values is only known at runtime. The following code gets the job done via creating a list:

```
def get_padded_tuple(self, value, tuple_length):
    if tuple_length>0:
        ret = [value] + [None]*(tuple_length - 1)
        return tuple(ret)
    raise IndexError('Tuple Length Not Supported', tuple_length)

def test_get_padded_tuple(self):
    pprint(self.get_padded_tuple('a', 1))
    pprint(self.get_padded_tuple('a', 5))
```

Is there a more efficient way, without the overhead of creating a list?

**Edit:** I have a module that takes a time series of tuples (date, value1, value2 etc) and adds missing dates (date, None, ...) - this is essentially a left outer join kind of thing. Different time series have elements with different lengths, this is why I wanted to use tuples of the same length as the element in the time series, if there is a lightweight way to accomplish that - otherwise I can just use lists.

Comment: Why do you need to produce tuples of variable length *in the first place*? That sounds like there is an overall problem that needs addressing.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I modified my question to answer your comment.

Comment: But you have just one value, so you could just use indexing into the produced time series? Why do you need to match up lengths?

Comment: Or is this the module you are coding? So you need to produce additional tuples that match the rest of the series. I'd just use `empty = (len(series) - 1) * (None,)` then, *once*, and produce new tuples with `(newdate,), + empty`  each time you are producing an interpolated value.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, I am developing this left outer join-y function. Thank you for your suggestion  - I will benchmark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return (value,) + (None,) * (tuple_length - 1)
```

or

```
return tuple(None if i else value for i in xrange(tuple_length))
```

or

```
return tuple([value, None][i > 0] for i in xrange(tuple_length))
```

Comment: return tuple(None if i else value for i in xrange(tuple_length)) is exactly what I am looking for! Thanks a bunch!